# Python boolean truth tests

Tags: python, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)

Does Python have an equivalent of the `ternary` operator?:

```
( x < 5 ? 1 : 0 )
```

Or must I express the same thing with an `if-else` pair?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
1 if x < 5 else 0
```

In code written for very old versions of Python, you may also see:

```
x < 5 and 1 or 0
```

However, the conditional expression form is preferred for Python 2.5 and later.

Comment: Note that the `and`/`or` will fail if the value after `and` is false.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks. I'll accept your answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: Of course, in this particular case, you can just use `x < 5` as the value itself, or `bool(x < 5)` if `x` is a particularly weird type.

Comment: @ignacio, that does not seem to be the case. `0 and 0 or 1` returns `1` for me, just tested on Python 2.3 through 2.7

Comment: And the `if:/else:` should be preferred in code that has to work in Python <2.5. I find that reading/fixing/refactoring code with the `and/or` variant is much less productive than the 4-5 line version

Answer (score 1):

Python has:

```
1 if x < 5 else 0
```

or the old style:

```
x < 5 and 1 or 0
```